# XCode, Leaks instrument not working, "an error occurred trying to capture allocations data"

Tags: xcode, instruments

I'm trying to debug some memory leaks in an iOS application.

Previously I have used the Instruments/Leaks tool provided with XCode
and the "Mark Generation" button in that tool to successfully locate sources
of the memory leaks.

However, now I get the error in the title of this question.

There were some things to do that worked last time, at least this helped before:

- Edit Scheme -> Run -> Run -> Diagnostics -> Enable:  "Malloc stack"

[This developer forums thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115628) offers some work-arounds, like profiling with debug build,
but that does not help, at least in my particular case.

Is there some other work-arounds or likely things I'm doing that prevent the Leak tool
from working?

Answer (score 8):

One thing I noticed is that it gives that error when testing with iOS simulator,
but when *profiling on a real iOS device it works*.